# Finding minimum cost to reach the end of array

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

An array of costs was given. You can either take two jumps forward or one jump backward. If you land on a particular index, you have to add the cost to your total. Find the minimum cost needed to cross the array or reach the end of the array.

**Input:**

```
5 (Number of elements in the array)

[9,4,6,8,5] (Array)

1 (Index to start)
```

**Output:**

```
12
```

Explanation: We start from index 1, jump to 3 and then jump out for a total cost of 8+4=12.

How can we build the DP solution for this?

Comment: is the cost non negative?

Comment: Ok, I assume cost must be zero or positive; otherwise the minimum cost path could be an infinite path (forward, backward, backward - with the cost of this negative)

Comment: The cost can be negative

Comment: @TavishJain Cost can't be negative... as that would always lead to the minimum cost of negative of infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursive program with Dp

```
//cur will the final destination that is last element at first execution
//N is no of elements
int Dp[N]={0};
Dp[0]=element[0]; //initial condition
least_path(cur,*elements,N)
{
   if(cur>N-1 || cur<0)
     return INT_MAX;
  if(Dp[cur])
   return Dp[cur];
  int temp1=least_path(cur-2,*elements,N)+element[cur];
  int temp2=least_path(cur+1,*elements,N)+element[cur];
  Dp[cur]=min(temp1,temp2);
  return Dp[cur];
}
```

Comment: This recursion won't solve. Goes into an infinite loop - can easily check with a small array of 5 elements and unfolding the stack.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Dijkstra's algorithm(graph)** for solving this problem.

Follow these steps:

**1.** ***Generate Weighted directed graph*** by connecting a node of **ith index** with nodes at **(i-1)th** and **(i+2)th** index with their cost(if possible).

**2.** Apply Dijkstra's algorithm to ***find the shortest route between the initial node(index) and the target node(index)***.

Comment: Can't we use DP for it ?

Comment: @TavishJain Yes you can use DP... but that will work on the same principle of selecting the optimal value out of two reachable indices.

Comment: @TavishJain, Dijkstra's algorithm *is* DP.

Answer (score 2):

DP based solution - Fill up 1-D cost array in bottom up manner. Involves 2 steps:

1. On reaching index i, check and update cost if we it can be improved by arriving on it from index i+1.
2. Update the cost of reaching element at i+2.

Time complexity: O(n), where n is length of input array.

```
    # Python3 snippet  
    # Inputs: startIndex, array A of non negative integers
    # Below snippet assumes A has min length 3 beginning from the startIndex. We can handle smaller arrays with base cases - thus, not listing them out explicitly

    import math

    costs = [math.inf] * len(A)
    costs[startIndex] = A[startIndex]   
    costs[startIndex+1] = A[startIndex] + A[startIndex+1] + min(A[startIndex+1], A[startIndex-1] if startIndex >=0 else A[startIndex+1])

    N = len(A)
    for i in range(startIndex, N):
        if i+1 < N:
            costs[i] = min(costs[i], costs[i+1] + A[i])
        if i + 2 < N:                 
            costs[i+2] = costs[i] + A[i+2]

    print(min(costs[-1], costs[-2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used `path` to represent all the visited nodes visited so far
`res` to represent the result so far

```
import sys
infi = sys.maxsize


def optimum_jump_recurse(arr, curr_pos, cost, path, res):
    if curr_pos in path or cost > res or curr_pos < 0:
        return infi
    elif curr_pos > len(arr) - 1:
        if cost < res:
            res = cost
        return cost

    res = optimum_jump_recurse(arr, curr_pos + 2, cost + arr[curr_pos],
                               path | {curr_pos}, res)
    backward_cost = optimum_jump_recurse(arr, curr_pos - 1,
                                         cost + arr[curr_pos],
                                        path | {curr_pos}, res)
    if res == backward_cost == infi:
        return res
    res = min(res, backward_cost)
    actual_cost = res - cost
    return res


nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100]
# nums = [1, 2, 3]
# nums = [1]
# nums = [1, 2]
# nums = [1, 2, 3, 100, 200]
# nums = [1, 1000, 3, 100, 200]
# nums = [1, 1, 3, 100, 200]
# nums = [1, 1, 3, 5, 100, 200]
# nums = [1, 2, 3, 100, 4]


def optimum_jump(nums):
    return optimum_jump_recurse(nums, 0, 0, set(), infi)


print(optimum_jump(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ solution (dijikstras)

```
int minDist(vector<bool> &visited, vector<int> &dist, int n){
    int m = INT_MAX, res = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(!visited[i] && m > dist[i])
            m = dist[i], res = i;
    return res;
}

int minJump(int *arr, int n){
    vector<bool> visited(n, false);
    vector<int> dist(n, INT_MAX);

    dist[0] = 0;
    for(int c = 0; c < n - 1; c++){
        int u = minDist(visited, dist, n);
        visited[u] = true;

        if(u + 2 < n && !visited[u + 2] && dist[u] + arr[u + 2] < dist[u + 2])
            dist[u + 2] = dist[u] + arr[u + 2];
        if(u - 1 >= 0 && !visited[u - 1] && dist[u] + arr[u - 1] < dist[u - 1])
            dist[u - 1] = dist[u] + arr[u - 1];
    }
    return dist[n - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code would work to get min cost for index 0 to N-1

```
    int[] dp;
    boolean[] visited;
    
    int func(int pos, int N, int[] cost){
        
        if(pos == 0) return 0;
        if(dp[pos] != -1) return dp[pos];
        
        visited[pos] = true;

        int dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(pos-2 > -1 && !visited[pos-2]) dist = Math.min(dist, cost[pos-2] + func(pos-2,N,cost));
        if(pos+1 < N && !visited[pos+1]) dist = Math.min(dist, cost[pos+1] + func(pos+1,N,cost));
        
        return dp[pos] = dist;
    }
    
    int min_cost_to_reach_the_end(int[] cost){
        
        int N = cost.length;
        this.dp = new int[N];
        this.visited = new boolean[N];
        Arrays.fill(dp,-1);
        return func(N-1, N, cost);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but please check this.

```
public class MinimumCost {
public static void main(String ar[]){
    int arr[]={9,4,6,8,5};
    int startIndex=1;
    int DP[]=new int[arr.length];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        DP[i]=100000;//I just take this as maximum value .you can change it. 
    }
    DP[startIndex] = arr[startIndex]   ;
    DP[startIndex+2] = arr[startIndex] + arr[startIndex+2] + Math.min(arr[startIndex+2], arr[startIndex]);

    int n=arr.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if ((i+1)<n)
            DP[i] = Math.min(DP[i], (DP[i+1]) + arr[i]);
        if ((i + 2 )< n)                 
            DP[i+2] = DP[i] + arr[i+2];
    }
    System.out.println(Math.min(DP[arr.length-1],DP[arr.length-2]));

}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part of the code fixes what part of the problem please

Answer (score 0):

```
function solve(A_i) {
    A_i.sort((a,b) => a-b);

    let totalcost = A_i[0];
    for(let i=2; i<A_i.length;i++) {
        if(i + 1 == A_i.length -1) {
            totalcost = totalcost + A_i[i];
            break;
        }
        const preSum =  A_i[i] + A_i[i+2];
        const postSum = A_i[i] + A_i[i-1] + A_i[i+1];
        if(preSum <= postSum) {
            totalcost = totalcost + A_i[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            totalcost = totalcost + A_i[i];
            i = i-2;
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
    return totalcost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution in java using DP (iterative solution), constant memory and linear time complexity

```
long getJumpCost(int arr[]) {
    int length = arr.length;
    long dp[] = new long[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        dp[i] = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    dp[0] = arr[0];
    dp[2] = dp[0] + (long)arr[2];
    dp[1] = dp[2] + (long)arr[1];
    for(int i=3; i<length; i++) {
        dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], dp[i-2] + (long)arr[i]);
        dp[i-1] = Math.min(dp[i-1], dp[i] + (long)arr[i-1]);
    }
    long result = Math.min( dp[length-1], dp[length-2]);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n=3;
    bool flag = true;
    while(n)
    {
        
        //take last two bits then right shift
        int i = n%2;
        n=n/2;
        int j = n%2;
        n=n/2;
        
        //check with given pattern 01 & 10 is allowed only
        if((i==0 && j==1) || (i==1 && j==0))
        {
            //right pattern
        }
        else{
            //not allowed
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(flag)
    cout<<"YES";
    else
    cout<<"NO";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**JAVA Solution:  The solution takes O(n2)**

```
    int minCost[] = new int[N];
    Arrays.fill(minCost,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<A.length;j++){
            if(j == 0){
                minCost[j] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if(j-2>=0 && minCost[j-2]!=Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                minCost[j] = Math.min(minCost[j-2]+A[j-2],minCost[j]);
            }
            if(j+1<A.length && minCost[j+1]!=Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                minCost[j] = Math.min(minCost[j+1]+A[j+1],minCost[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    if(minCost[A.length-2]!= Integer.MAX_VALUE && minCost[A.length-1]!= Integer.MAX_VALUE){
        return Math.min(A[A.length-2]+minCost[A.length-2],minCost[A.length-1]+A[A.length-1]);
    }
    if(minCost[A.length-2]!= Integer.MAX_VALUE){
        return minCost[A.length-1]+A[A.length-1];
    }
    if(minCost[A.length-1]!= Integer.MAX_VALUE){
        return A[A.length-2]+minCost[A.length-2];
    }
    return -1;
```